# Can I build an AI that is more human beatable than this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I've been building an AI and currently I'm to the point where it mostly works as it should. I hit a few hitches at first, and had something that.. spazzed out. Now that is fixed, but there's a problem - this AI catches the ball 90% of the time and returns it, although somewhat slowly at times. I have yet to build the Attract mode of the game, but I can imagine... when that is in, the two AI will almost never score on eachother.

The game takes place on a 2D plane. The AI moves purely on X, locked into Z and Y while the ball moves on X and Y.

The playing field is set up like tennis, a 'net' in the center - 0,0,0, denotes the middle and the ball moves like a tennis ball does.

The AI (and player) uses two controls - 'Direction' to go either left or right, 1 for left, -1 for right, and a bool to trigger the ball return.

At the moment I just want it to 'miss' the ball every so often, not nearly perfectly every time.  I'm programming in C#, with the game engine being Unity3D - here's my code for the AI engine thus far:

```
void AIHandle()
{
    DetectBalls();

    if (GameController.Instance.Balls.Count < 1) {
        GetFlipperButton = false;
    }

    if (BallPosition) {
        BallPosit = BallPosition.position;
        BallX = BallPosit.x;
        //BallVelPosit = BallPosition.gameObject.rigidbody.velocity;
        //BallPosit.x += BallVelPosit.x;
        //BallPosit.y += BallVelPosit.y;
        //BallVelPosit.y -= Physics.gravity.y;
        //BallHitPredictor = new Vector3 (BallPosit.x, 0, 0);
        transformPoint = transform.InverseTransformPoint(BallPosit);

        //////////////////
        Vector3 Heading = BallPosit - transform.position;
        if (BallX > 0) {


            Debug.Log(Heading.sqrMagnitude);

            // THe ball is to the left //

            if (transformPoint.z < 0f)
            {
                Direction = 1;
            }
            // The ball is to the right //
            if (transformPoint.z > 0f)
            {
                Direction = -1;
            }

            if (Heading.sqrMagnitude < 30.0f)
            {
                Direction = 0;
            }



        } else {
            Retreat();
        }
    } else {
        Retreat();
    }

    MovementDirection = Mathf.Lerp(MovementDirection, Direction, 2.0f);

}

private void Retreat()
{
    float DistanceToCenter = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, PlayerStartPosition);

    Vector3 CenterPointOrient = transform.InverseTransformPoint(PlayerStartPosition);

    if (DistanceToCenter >= 1f) {
        if (CenterPointOrient.z > 0) {
            Direction = -1;
        } else {
            Direction = 1;
        } 
    } else {
        Direction = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Random to the rescue!

Comment: Your AI should have an error somewhere. Chance to make mistake is the easiest. But to make it more human-alike you will have to do much more, simulate human reaction delay, hand movement inaccuracy, etc.

Comment: do a random int between 0 and 100. if <5, give it a perfect, if between 5 and 10, less perfect, if between 11 and 15, total miss, etc etc

Comment: Careful modulation of random factors will make the difference between an AI that seems more beatable and an AI that seems like it's losing on purpose. Rather than use a random range that remains constant or applying a fixed probability table, try adding a random offset to the ball's predicted landing point that scales with the time or distance until the ball lands as well as the ball's speed. This would simulate a player's variable certainty about the landing prediction, since it's easier to predict the ball if it is slow and close to its eventual landing point.